# Can't access BIOS or boot my Windows

Tags: windows-7, bios, grub, rescue

I had Ubuntu 12.04 + Windows 7 installed, I didn't like Ubuntu hence I deleted the partition.
But I forgot to fix the MBR.
Also I cannot access the mutiboot option using <kbd>F12</kbd> at startup.
So when I start, I get the Lenovo screen with <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> options but none work, and then the screen shows:

```
unknown filesystem
grub rescue-
```

with commands ls I get:

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (cd 0)
```

and with set I get:

```
prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt3
```

may be because I had installed my Ubuntu in gpt3 partition

can anybody fix this problem?

Comment: Possible related thread: http://superuser.com/questions/179025/windows-7-not-booting-after-ubuntu-partition-deletion?rq=1

Comment: Is it a laptop or a desktop? Could we have any details on your motherboard/laptop manufacturer?

Comment: It could be `F1` or `F10` or `Del`.

Comment: MBR is a fully separate issue from Bios access and is unrelated. Try spamming the `F2` key on boot (hit it repeatedly from boot until you're in bios or back and grub rescue and report back) to see if it just isn't registering right. Is it safe to assume when you reach grub rescue your keyboard is registering keystrokes?

Answer (score -1):

I would load the Windows installer DVD into the DVD tray, and change the BIOS to boot from it. That's what did it for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: So, to explain the downvote:  First you are overlooking the issue that they say they "Can't access bios" (even though the issues are unrelated to MBR).  But beyond that, Super User wants questions to be relevant for future users, so it would be helpful for you to explain what to do next if the OP could get the Windows disc booted.  It may seem obvious to some, but not always the case.